# Restricting access using IP address / Network Redirection?

Tags: web-server, routing, ip-address, security

I have a situation where we have a web server (lets call it A) that is hosting a set of HTTP based services.

Due to some client requirements, this web server is not open to the outside world but rather has an IP address based restriction to allow only a certain fixed set of IP addresses.

The idea is that there will be another server that will be the outward public facing server (lets call it B) and this server will then redirect all requests to server A - which accepts requests only from Server A.

2 questions :-

1. Does having such a server configuration add any value or any benefit which could not be achieved by just having "server A" alone?
2. If "server B" is only basically doing a redirect, can I do it using some networking hardware itself like a router etc rather than having a web server do it? And would that be more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Unless Server B is doing some type of transformation/routing there isn't much benefit to the configuration based on the limited information given.  In many situations, Server B would be a  hardware load balancer or other "application delivery controller" that would be performing traffic balancing/routing based on layer 7 info, a balancing algorithm, etc, thus adding some type of value.

This is of course all dependent on a lot of assumptions made (e.g. what is meant by "redirect", what sort of additional security do you believe is gained from B, etc).

Comment: Its possible that the client is insisting on having server B is because their own IT want to outsource the risk of securing a public facing server. By "redirect" i mean that server B will transfer any HTTP request made to it from the public internet to server A and convey response from Server A back to the originator of the request. As of now, thats all it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Why can't you dual home the server with one pointing to the client and the other internally?